# Is it possible to use a single celery instance to connect to multiple brokers?

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, celery

I have a use case where there are two RabbitMQs which I would like to connect to, RabbitMQ instance A and instance B. Assume for the moment that I cannot combine these two instances into a single RabbitMQ instance and they *must* be separate. Please note that these two instances have different exchanges/queues and are not by-any-means replications of the data or messages.

Is it possible, using a single celery application, to connect to two brokers, and their exchanges/queues at: `amqp://<instance-a>:5672` and `amqp://<instance-b>:5672`?

I have looked through the documentation and this doesn't seem to be possible, celery seems to be monolithic for the most part--however I am relatively new to celery (and Python) so I may have missed something.

Comment: You want Celery to perform its task management using the two brokers? I'm asking because I'm pretty sure you could have Celery use one broker for task management and have the tasks use a second broker for some *other* purpose.

Comment: @Louis I guess I only really need Celery to perform task management against one of the brokers, but I still need to consume messages and act on them from a second connection. I was thinking that meant using Celery for task management against both. The split is basically an external message queue which I have little control over and an internal message queue, and I was hoping I could build up a single application around both connections. Originally I was thinking I might need to get into multiprocessing/multithreading but didn't want to go down that route if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might be "abusing" celery as a rabbitmq **consumer**. Using rabbitmq as a message queue (or event queue) is a great idea, but you don't need to use celery to consume from it (and frankly - since celery is not adapted for this kind of work, it would probably bite you later on)

So you better choose some rabbiqmq client abstraction  library ([Kombu](http://kombu.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/examples.html) [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.10.0/), [Puke](https://github.com/majek/puka) are the major python options) and build your self a decent consumer.

You can also try to use the [shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) for rabbitmq. That can be used to "shovel" messages from one queue/exchange to another. Might also work

Comment: Thanks for that level of insight! I've begun to suspect that this is a very true statement, allow me to ask this though: assuming that I use celery specifically for task related workflows from one queue, and still need to consume from the other queue, does it make more sense to produce two separate applications or handle the workload in a multi-process/multi-threaded manner?

Comment: I believe that Separating applications should be a decision based on the "domain boundries" and "bounded contexts". It It really is one app. then keep it one app - you can also run one app with several processes running the same code base (For example a django app, that also has a process that consumes from rabbitmq and call various handlers in the django app) . If different business logic then separate (going the microservice path) and you can use rabbitmq to communicate data,events and commands

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time you've taken. One last question/request if you don't mind: are there any search terms/topics/resources you could point me to that discuss the concept of running one app with several processes from the same code base? I'm assuming this is just multi-processing/multi-threading but if it is something different it would be helpful to know what to look for!

Comment: Actually multi processing/multi threading is a little different. But you can think about the usual Django app: You'll have a wsgi web server run the web process - and might be spawning multiple processes with multiple threads each (I think the default uwsgi server configuration is 4 processes) . We usually would also have at least one node of celery workers - again each worker is a standalone process running the same code base with  a different entry point. So you actually already encountered this.. as long as the app state isn't "in process" or "in memory" you are good

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it!

Comment: Hey Sean, would you mind accepting the answer?  It helps other users who stumble here to find out if this is actually a useful answer (and also with my points here..)

Comment: I was intending to, but had originally planned to leave it open a couple days longer to see if there were any other responses given.

Comment: No problems.. No rush